# android parse.com saving installation error. object not found for update

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm getting this error below and have no idea what to do about it. I don't even know what code to post here because i can't seem to find where in my code is causing this error. There is one more important thing to mention: This error doesn't happen on my first test device which is a HTC incredible running android 4.0.4, but my second test device which is a samsung tablet running 4.4.2 does receive this error.

edit: I think that it has something to do with my parse installation object, as it doesn't save into the database for the 2nd device. In my code I have:

```
 ParseInstallation UserPushObj = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
 System.out.println(UserPushObj.getObjectId());
```

And it returns a parse installation object with an object id that isn't in the database. I try to

```
 UserPushObj.saveInBackground();
```

but it doesn't save. Can someone point me on the right track as to what I can do to fix it?

```
E/ParseCommandCache(8040): Failed to run command.
E/ParseCommandCache(8040): com.parse.ParseException: object not found for update
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.ParseCommand.onPostExecute(ParseCommand.java:334)
 E/ParseCommandCache(8040):     at com.parse.ParseRequest$5.then(ParseRequest.java:321)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.ParseRequest$5.then(ParseRequest.java:318)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:364)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:410)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:402)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$300(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:311)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:308)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$300(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:311)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:308)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/ParseCommandCache(8040):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: just delete the app from your device or emulator and clean the project. Then try again. It should be good to check the manifest file as well.Hope this helps.

Comment: the same trouble I had? Have you any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the ParseInstallation is not exist in Parse DB...
Therefore one solution that I found is uninstall/install app.

Answer (score 1):

Force Parse to reinitialize by removing its files

```
public static void removeCurrentInstallation(Context context) {
    File filesDir = context.getDir("Parse", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean exists = filesDir.exists();
    File[] files = filesDir.listFiles();
    if (exists && filesDir.length() > 0) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile())
                file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

use it in Application class

```
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.i("Parse", "Installation saved successfully");
            } else {
                Log.e("Parse", "Installation failed to save: " + e);
                if (e.getCode() == ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
                    removeCurrentInstallation(getApplicationContext());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```