# Re-register device on Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

When I delete a device from core on Parse, in order to see it on the list again, I am deleting the application on phone and then downloading it again. Then, I can see the device on the registered devices.

But, what I want to do is to see the device on the list without downloading the application again.
How can I produce this?

Comment: Where do you put your ParseInstallation code, in which class?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/41548143/3487232

Answer (score 0):

The Parse core table I think you're referring to is a list of installations of your application.

The data in that table is grabbed on first run of the application on the mobile device when Parse.Initialize(...) is called.

Once the device has registered with Parse it has no reason to do this again.

Why are you removing devices from this list in the first place?

Comment: At first run of the application as you told I can see device on the list. But there was a problem and I had to delete the device from list. Then I noticed that if I delete it, no matter what I do I could not see the device on the registered devices untill I deleted the application and downloaded it again. If again a problem occurs, and I delete the device from list, is reinstalling the app only way in order to see the device on the list again?

Comment: From my understanding the Android Parse tools only register the device on first run. One test you could run is to delete the data for you application and relaunch and see if this reregisters your device.